# Escape de html en angular

Tags: angular, ionic

no se si este bien mi pregunta, y si no me corrigen, resulta que estoy mostrando en un card información que viene de una api.
pero al mostrar me sale con todo sus etiquetas html, es decir, como viene de con texto enriquecido, al traerlo viene con etiquetas como , &nbsp, , y cosas así, me pregunto, si hay manera de que se interprete eso, para que el texto se vea correctamente, o en su defecto poder filtrar todo lo q llega y dejarlo texto plano sin etiquetas.
la manera en que lo traigo es la siguiente

```
<div class="contenido">
      {{ content?.Descripcion }}
  </div>
```

estoy usando angular 7, ojala exista una manera sencilla de realizarlo, saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es sencillo, solo tienes que usar la propiedad [innerHTML](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation) :

```
<div class="contenido" [innerHTML] = "content?.Descripcion" ></div>
```

Comment: si! justo tambien lo encontre de aqui, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013217/how-to-render-string-with-html-tags-in-angular-4 pero gracias!!!